# Linking to external android apps through html

Tags: android, html, css, android-webview

I'm a First time developer who is developing a basic WebView based app for android devices. I have some links that lead to profiles on facebook, twitter & instagram etc. At the moment whenever these links are clicked the relevant profiles open but in website form and not app. How can I make these links open the relevant app instead of the website. For example whenever I click on instagram it loads the mobile website for instagram instead of launching the actual app. Also if I have a telephone number set using href="tel: how can I set it to launch the phone app with the telephone number filled in. Sorry if these are stupid questions but I am very new to app development and am still learning. Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the application specific URL schemes:

A good read on what this is:

https://fokkezb.nl/2013/08/26/url-schemes-for-ios-and-android-1/

Once you understand what this is you will need to do some research to find the URL scheme and correct url for every app you want to target

Example: `fb://profile/`

Phone number this might work: `<a href="tel:2125551212">2125551212</a>`

Comment: Thank you for your very quick reply. The telephone number is already coded like you put it above but it just loads a "web page not available" page. It works like you'd expect it to on a normal web browser, just not WebView. I will have a read at that link you provided and hopefully find what I need. FYI.... The apps that I am looking to link to are facebook, twitter, instagram & youtube.